# Google Maps dependency based on html drop list

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

This is my first post and I hope I can get some help since I am relatively new to the development arena, please excuse me if my questions are a bit stupid.

I am trying to make sort of a dashboard implementing a dependency from a drop down list in html - let's say that based on the drop down list value selected, a div tag containing a google maps reference should be updated.

For example:

I choose a continent from the drop down list, and then Google will shift its view on that area, later on showing customized points of interest on the map. Can someone help me or suggest a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - it should give you hints on how to make your question better. In general, showing your effort (what you have done so far) will inspire better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the Google Maps Javascript API (I assume you've already done this):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

JS:

```
var map;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center:            new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom:              10,
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.maps-input').on('change', function() {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': $(this).val()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            else
                alert('A location could not be found. ' + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Then add a dropdown (or any type of input) with class `maps-input` to your page and a div with class `map-canvas` (of course you can change these class names to whatever you want).